# Use random values ​extracted from a request in another request in jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

On request 1, the values ​​(animal, celebrity, dev...) are extracted and saved in a variable to be used later.
In request 2 I want to use these extracted values, but randomly.

I'm not having success doing this.

**URL where I extract the values ​​and save them in a variable:** https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories

**URL where I want to use the values ​​randomly:**
[https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category={category}](https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=%7Bcategory%7D)

**I extract the values ​​with json extractor and save in the "category" variable, this works very well.**

[image: category]

**I want to use the randomly extracted values ​​in the next call!**

[image: erro]
[image: erro2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify "Match No" to "0" in JSON Extractor and use the variable ${categoria} in next request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract values once and run a random query multiple times it makes sense to consider using [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [__V() functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) combination.

```
${__V(categoria_${__Random(1,${categoria_matchNr},)},)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)